# Errors in libraries not shown - Code Igniter / PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

*Errors* in libraries in Code Igniter aren't displayed in some server configurations.
How can that setting be overridden manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line `ini_set('display_errors', true);` somewhere in your controller before you called the library or in the beginning of the library and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the main index page add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. I recommend you remove this once you are ready to publish the website.

Answer (score 0):

change environment in your main index.php file to development.

search for line `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`

Comment: what ENVIRONMENT you have defined?

Comment: development. But thats not it, because I can see errors from the controllers but not from the libraries.

Comment: Can you specify what do you want, and how you want to see those errors? If you load some library in controller and there will be some errors you should see them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the loading of model this is a frequent mistake even if you show error

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

when model is not loaded properly error wont show

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```